# Is it possible to update the expiration date of a cert with certbot, but not update the cert contents?

Tags: ssl, lets-encrypt, certbot

I'm using certbot with letsencrypt to generate ssl certificates for a few subdomains on a few sites.  The certs are generated using the --manual flag with a DNS challenge.

It's now time to renew a dozen or so certificates, is it possible to do this without changing the certificate body itself, or is the expiration date built into the certificate itself?

My goal is to manually renew a bunch of certs without having to redeploy the servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expiration data is part of the certificate. Just look at the cert with a text editor and you will see this.
 with longer expiration dates. If what you want to do was possible the expiration data would be worthless.

To get around this purchase certificates with longer validity.

Note: Effective March 1, 2018, CA/Browser Forum Baseline Requirements restrict the maximum validity of DV and OV SSL certificates to 825 days. The change goes into effect March 1, 2018 and affects all CAs and all types of SSL/TLS Certificates. See [GlobalSign](https://www.globalsign.com/en/blog/ssl-certificate-validity-capped-at-maximum-two-years/).

Comment: Thanks a ton for taking the time to explain.  To clarify, are you saying that the expiration date is coded into your private key and chain, or does it come from the CA during validation?

Comment: It is in the certificate.

Comment: Why is 825-days??